# How to navigate to the next screen on TouchableOpacity click

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making an app, I've still only made the splash screen. But, I want to know how to navigate to the next screen on a touchable opacity click. I don't want to navigate by creating a specific function for the pages. I want to navigate by importing the page.

I have shown my code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const src2 = {
  uri: "https://o.remove.bg/downloads/e6dc1218-7a94-4c86-a3b9-6baed9ee6c63/images-removebg-preview.png"
}

const src = {
  uri: "https://o.remove.bg/downloads/7ce84ac7-f275-434c-a294-11a8b2e56e2b/pngtree-halo-victory-light-effect-png-image_1727940-removebg-preview.png"
}

function Levels({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <levels />
  );
}

export default props => {
    
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Sketch 3D': 'https://dafonttop.com/wp-data/s/870/1870/file/sketch-3d.regular.otf',
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>My app</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#CFA240",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: "Sketch 3D",
    fontSize: 50,
    color: "#fff",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 150
  },
  glow: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 45,
    left: 20,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
  mop: {
    top: 45,
    left: 10,
    height: 225,
    width: 225,
  }, 
  images: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 220,
  },
  button: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 150,
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 16,
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: "#CFA240",
    borderStyle: "dashed",
    elevation: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontFamily: "Sketch 3D",
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 25,
  }
})
```

PS I have to go to the next screen by importing the file

Thank you.

Comment: You have to set navigation in your app https://reactnavigation.org/

Comment: Can you please answer by adding the correct code.

Comment: Its referenced at many places already, there are so many tutorials in this regard, only if you would have searched. Here is official react native guide to set navigation in your app https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

Answer (score 1):

```js
     <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
             <Text>GO TO HOME</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.